# Python: list range: int to string conversion

Tags: python, list, range

In Python, how would i convert the range

```
Range1 = list(range(1, 11))
```

where output is

> 1, 2, 3,... , 10

to a list of strings so that the output is

> '01', '02', '03'..., '10'

Note that I need the leading 0 in front of the single int.

Comment: So perhaps `[format(i, '02d') for i in range(1, 11)]`.

Comment: That'll do. Thanks.